# NodeJS with MongoDB - best practice to instantiate "db" variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently trying to get a grip on NodeJS / Express / MongoDB and read several tutorials about it. In [this tutorial by Christopher Buecheler](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/), consider step 5 and 6:

In `app.js`, the following code is added:

```
// ...
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

app.get('/userlist', routes.userlist(db));
// ...
```

And in `routes/index.js` you can find the handler which belongs to the `/userlist` route:

```
exports.userlist = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        // do stuff
    };
};
```

I was confused by passing the db object to every handler, since, in my opinion, it creates a lot of redundancy, because you need to pass it to every handler and wrap an additional function around it. So I tried to add the initialisation of the `db` object into the `routes/index.js` file which seems to work fine and saves a lot of lines when dealing with more urls:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');

var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

exports.userlist = function(req, res) {
  // do stuff
};
```

Since I'm new to MongoDB, are there any downsides doing it this way? What advantages would it have to pass the `db` object to every handler instead?

Comment: I'm not sure about whether it's ok or not but I don't think creating a new variable is more efficient than just passing an existing one to the routers.

Comment: The first one (the one from the tutorial) is wrapped in `function(db)` because it is passed in from `app.js`, while the second one I came up with instantiates `db` in `routes/indes.js`, making it available to every request handler and removes the need of wrapping every handler inside `function(db)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I do it like you did, I instantiate it in the place that uses it.

But I have seen other people do it like in this tutorial, passing it over every time and I think it does make sense if you need to use that db in **multiple** places, think if you had many different files that all need that database... now instantiating it every time, that would be redundant.

Well, that's my 2 cents... not sure there is any "good" answer to this... It might be a good practice to keep it in app.js in case you need it all over the place, but I don't think there is any disadvantage of doing otherwise if only used at a specific place.